# Recording data with has_and_belongs_to_many relationship in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, has-and-belongs-to-many

I m new in rails and I have a problem recording data in database with a has_and_belongs_to_many relationship.

I have a `has_and_belongs_to_many` relationship between `events` and `participants`

Participant:

```
class Participant < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :events, join_table: :events_participants
end
```

Event:

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :participants, join_table: :events_participants
end
```

In an `event` form, i have a`collection_check_boxes` to select participants:

```
<%= collection_check_boxes(:event, :participants, Participant.all, :id, :name) %>
```

And lastly in the `events_controller`, I define the require params like this:

```
params.require(:event).permit(participants: [:participant_id])
```

The rest of code is the code auto-generated by rails g scaffold command.

So, the question is: when i select one (or more)  `Participant` in `Event` form through the checkboxes and press the submit button, I can see the `INSERT INTO Event` SQL generated, but nothing about `INSERT INTO events_participants`

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Can you post the server log generated?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line

```
<%= collection_check_boxes(:event, :participants, Participant.all, :id, :name) %>
```

should be

```
<%= collection_check_boxes(:event, :participant_ids, Participant.all, :id, :name) %>
```

And you also need to change the below

```
params.require(:event).permit(participants: [:participant_id])
```

to

```
params.require(:event).permit(participant_ids: [])
```